# Exclude woocommerce products with no price set- wp query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the woocommerce products with almost similar regular price.
For eg: Regular price of the current product is $1000

and some other products with prices are

1. product1  - $1001
2. product2  - $1006
3. product3  - $996
4. product4  - $999
5. product5  - $1003
6. product6  - $1001
7. product7  - $1005
8. product8  - $1010
9. product9  - $998
10. product10 - $990

Now if I was suppose to show 4 nearest products by price then they would be product 1,6,4,9

Because above seemed a bit difficult to me so I tried to get

- two product with price greater than $1000  &
- two product with price greater than $1000

Here are the arguments for wp query that I tried

```
$args =  array(
              'post_type'=>'product',
              'posts_per_page'=>2, 
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'meta_key' => '_price',
              'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                'key' => '_price',
                                'value' => 1000,
                                'compare' => '<',
                                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                              ),
                            )
             );
```

I guess it should give me 2 nearest products with prices less 1000

But issue is it also gives me products for which the price is not set ..So                                                   I want to exclude the products with no price set..

Thanks in advance

Comment: add relation=> 'AND' setting and an array for the price set requirement

Comment: @RST thanks a lot for the speedy reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple meta queries, so you could add one to check if the price is higher then 0:

```
$args =  array(
              'post_type'=>'product',
              'posts_per_page'=>2, 
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value',
              'meta_key' => '_price',
              'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                'key' => '_price',
                                'value' => 1000,
                                'compare' => '<',
                                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                              ),
                                array(
                                'key' => '_price',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'compare' => '>',
                                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                              )
                            )
             );
```

You do not need to set the relation parameter, as it is set to "AND" by default.

Comment: hey thanks a lot .. I tried this code but was looking for the result at wrong place , so thought its not working.MY bad... Can you help me on the basic issue that is fetching the products with nearest prices. As the code given by you doesn't work like that

Comment: You mean fetching for example 5 products closest in price? Both higher and lower?

Comment: ya if thats possible or atleast  highher .. Then I can run two different queries to get both  seperately

Comment: The code above should give you the 2 closest products with a price less then 1000. So you only need to change DESC to ASC and change "<" to ">" to receive the 2 highest I think. And you can remove the higher then 0 check since you don't need it if you find prices higher then 1000 anyway.

Comment: it works perfect in case of price higher than but doesn't work in case of lower than.. I guess due to check to exclude free products.. may be instead of   'value' => 0, 'compare' => '>',    compare should have not equal