# Remove Woocommerce free products from a WP_Query loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I am using the php below in an enhanced text widget to display a list of recently added products.  It  works fine.

However, my shop also has free products (Price 0), and I do not want these displayed in the list.

What to I need to add to the code to exclude free products?

```
<?php  
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with wp_query only

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'meta_query'   => [[
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ]]
    ) );
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745002/exclude-woocommerce-products-with-no-price-set-wp-query) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks Mtxz.  I tested this and its works.  New products with price are added to the list in the widget.  Free products are not.